# Pass data into Facebook tab app, using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that you can pass data into a Facebook tab app using the app_data query string parameter like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/<page>/11206786180924?id=112086456180924&sk=app_5691879654669760566&app_data=some_data_here
```

Using PHP, I know that you would decode the app_data from the signed_request POST parameter.

However, my app can only use the JS SDK. I dont have access to any backend functionality.

Is there a way to retrieve the app_data using only Javascript?

The signed_request is passed with the authReponse from the JS SDK, however, when this is decoded, it doesnt contain the app_data.

Comment: You want to retrieve app_data from a url? Is that right?

Comment: Well the app_data parameter isn't passed into the app iframe I don't think, so I don't think that would work. I was expecting there would be a way to retrieve it from the JS SDK, most likely in the authResponse - but its not there. I'm just looking for any other solution.